# How do I access a variable from an stdClass object within an Array of Arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, stdclass

I did a `print_r` on my array `$total` and it returned the following:

```
Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( 
[generated] => 6 [magnitude] => 3 [log_pk] => 14 [result] => 0.5000 ) )
Array ( ) Array ( )
```

I need to be able to print out `log_pk` from within the `stdClass Object`. I have tried `print $total[0]->log_pk` but that was unsuccessful. The error was `Undefined offset: 0`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's with the `Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Arr...` at the beginning?

Comment: It looks like that array is at index 4?

Comment: @DaveChen It looks like consecutive print_r on empty arrays.

Comment: This `$total` variable is the result of a MySQL query, each `Array()` I'm assuming represents a particular day as the query was based on the last 7 days. I also tried, `$total[4][0]['log_pk]` and there was no luck.

Comment: @PRPGFerret in which case he wouldn't get `Undefined offset: 0`

Comment: You could always run a recursive function to iterate through the MD array

Comment: So this is within a loop, you should check if the index `0` exists first. `if (isset($total[0])) echo $total[o]->log_pk`

Comment: Dave, please post your answer, this is what I needed, thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is within a loop, you should check if the index 0 exists first.

```
if (isset($total[0])) echo $total[0]->log_pk
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this within a loop? If so then it looks like the array is empty on most iterations. Try:

`if (!empty($total)) print $total[0]->log_pk;`

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump()` displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

```
var_dump($total)
```

[PHP: var_dump - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: I'm trying to get a particular value out of the `$total` array, not dump the whole lot?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your print_r is inside a loop.

```
while(true){
    $total = some_function();
    print_r($total);
    if($condition) break;
}
// Here - outside the loop, is not the right place for the print_r();
```

If you want you print outside the loop, you would change `$total = some_function();` to `$total[] = some_function();` and then you can do `print_r($total[index])`